# magento catalog price rules not applied

Tags: php, magento

Magento 1.3.2.4 catalog price rules stopped applying after website was moved to another server. Cron job is not giving any errors, however PHP version on a new server is higher. The only thought that comes to mind is that some PHP libraries might be missing thus cron.php is still not getting executed properly thus catalog price rules are not applied? Does someone know what are obligatory PHP libraries for cron.php to run properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your new server meets the magento requirements and php cli also matches those requirements

Comment: Requirements are met, magento is running just fine, except for this one issue.

Comment: how did you verify the requirements and how did you verified this for php cli

Comment: Well, if everything is running then I assume the requirements are met. Besides, cron.php does not generate any errors to work with. I've enabled error messages, still nothing.

Comment: Hows everything running if your complaining here :) so go ahead and check the requirements for both php configs for webserver and command line interface

Comment: Apparently Magento 1.3 is not compatible with PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1):

I had a nasty issue the other weekend when our magento catalog price rules stopped applying. After some digging we realized that the 'catalogrule_product_price' was empty even after we ran 'Apply Rules'. We also couldnt write to it directly. The table was corrupt apparently. After removing the table and recreating it everything was fixed. 
Hope it helps someone.

Community v 1.7.2